# Confusion about the isomorphism between directional derivatives and tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

A directional derivative $D_v: C^{\infty}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a derivation on $U$ since it is linear and obeys the product rule.

A typical definition of a tangent space at point $p$ on some manifold $M$  is simply the set of all derivations at $p$, and in both Tu and Lee's manifold introduction textbooks they heavily rely on the intuition/notion of a directional derivative to define the tangent space.

If $\mathcal D_p(M)$ is all derivations of $M$ at $p$, then there is an isomorphism between $\mathcal D_p(M)$ and the tangent space $T_p(M)$ of $M$ at $p$. Likewise, we also have that derivations such as directional derivatives $D_v\in \mathcal D_p(M)$ are isomorphic to tangent vectors $v \in T_p(M)$.

What I am confused about is how the definition is seemingly circular. To find a directional derivative $D_v$ we must be able to have a notion of the vector $v$, yet we are using $D_v$ to define $v$ via the isomorphism.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Max0815

Comment: There are 4 (or 3 or 5) equivalent definitions of tangent spaces. Tuples transforming according to rules between charts, equivalence classes of curves, derivations or even dualising cotangent vectors.  (Of course, cotangent vectors also has equivalent definitions..).

Comment: @user10354138 im specifically trying to understand tangent spaces from derivations in this case 

Comment: Which definition of $T_pM$ do you use?

Comment: @PaulFrost $T_p(M)$ should just be the set of all tangent vectors at $p\in M$ afaik? Regardless, I've been rereading Lee, Tu, and Spivak and I think I have a better understanding of this now 

Comment: If your question has been settled by "self-study", you should either delete it or write an answer.

Comment: bruh i know lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent space at a point $p$ is not defined via $D_v$ as v ranges over all directions. It is abstractly defined as the space of linear maps $H: C^{\infty}(U) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ which obey a product rule, i.e. $H(fg)=f(p)H(g)+g(p)H(f)$.
Hence, it is not apparent that every such member can be identified with a directional derivative

Comment: But a directional derivative is one possible derivation, so how would it work to serve as a tangent vector? We rely on the idea of directional derivatives to get the basis of any tangent space (with a coordinate chart ofc) to be partial derivative operators so surely there is something more fundamental of directional derivatives right?

Comment: directional derivatives are derivations as they satisfy both properties (linearity + product rule). Hence, it only remains to show that to every other "non-directional derivate-based" derivation there can be found a directional derivative with the same action. A proof for the latter (I strongly recommend looking it up - as this will clarify your question) can be found in Lee's Smooth manifold book (Proposition 3.2) for example. Hence, up to isomorphism the space of a all derivations is exactly the space of all directional derivatives

Comment: ok w/e i'll accept this. i more or less get the concept anyways :p